# Rectangle in QML that is transparent, except for the borders

Tags: qml

Is there a way in QML to create a Rectangle with `opacity: 0` that still have visible borders? If not, any suggestions on how to work around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No, opacity is applied for complete visual aspect of item (and opacity:0 makes item full invisible). If you want rectangle with borders and without background, use "transparent" as color.

```
Rectangle { border.color: "black"; color: "transparent" }
```